# Pandas dropna throwing ValueError: "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Tags: pandas

Pandas: 0.25.3
Python: 3.7.4

I have a data frame, and I want to remove the columns which contain only NaN values. That should be easy, because there is a Pandas DataFrame function which does exactly that—[dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). Here's my code:

```python
long_summary = long_summary.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
```

But that simple line throws an exception:

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

I cannot see how calling dropna would lead to this exception. What is going on and how do I fix it?

I'll include the whole exception stack just-in-case that makes the problem clearer:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-b4926abd4d81> in <module>
----> 1 long_summary = long_summary.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in dropna(self, axis, how, thresh, subset, inplace)
4860                 agg_obj = self.take(indices, axis=agg_axis)
4861 
-> 4862             count = agg_obj.count(axis=agg_axis)
4863 
4864             if thresh is not None:

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in count(self, axis, level, numeric_only)
7848                 result = Series(counts, index=frame._get_agg_axis(axis))
7849 
-> 7850         return result.astype("int64")
7851 
7852     def _count_level(self, level, axis=0, numeric_only=False):

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
5880             # else, only a single dtype is given
5881             new_data = self._data.astype(
-> 5882                 dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, **kwargs
5883             )
5884             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    579 
    580     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 581         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    582 
    583     def convert(self, **kwargs):

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    436                     kwargs[k] = obj.reindex(b_items, axis=axis, copy=align_copy)
    437 
--> 438             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    439             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    440 

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    557 
    558     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors="raise", values=None, **kwargs):
--> 559         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values, **kwargs)
    560 
    561     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors="raise", values=None, **kwargs):

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    641                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
    642                     vals1d = values.ravel()
--> 643                     values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True, **kwargs)
    644 
    645                 # TODO(extension)

c:\users\timregan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    698         if not np.isfinite(arr).all():
    699             raise ValueError(
--> 700                 "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to " "integer"
    701             )
    702 

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

(N.B. the data types of my columns are int64, Int32, and float64)

In the comments Scott asked for data to reproduce this issue. The redacted CSV is available on Dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm2w4oqsnrb6yqd/dropna.csv?dl=0).

```python
df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Temp\\dropna.csv')
df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
```

But be warned, the CSV is 3.3 GB and the resulting data frame has over 60 million rows. It tried cutting out rows, but it seems to need to be this long to trigger the error.

Comment: I've submitted this as an issue on the Pandas GitHub page too: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29734

Comment: Can you provide data that will duplicate this error?

Comment: Scott, I've added data, but be warned, it is big(3.3 GB). I've edited the question to point at the data. 
And to the editors trying to add a 'python' tag, please don't; this is a pandas specific question, adding a python tag is misleading.